# Can I use the inverse probability weighting estimators with censored outcome variables?

Tags: econometrics, propensity-scores, treatment-effect

I am analyzing the impact of financial aid for university students on hours spent working during the academic period by using inverse probability weighting(IPW) estimators ( the reason why I am using IPW estimators is due to multivalued treatments). Thus, the outcome variable is hours spent studying. However, my concern is that roughly 70% of samples actually do not work during the academic period, which means 0 hours. Thus, I am worried about the censored data problem. When searching for solutions for censored outcome variables, most of the information was about the survival analysis. But, I don't think this method is appropriate for my research question since my outcome variable is not related to time events.

Is that fine to use IPW estimators with the censored outcome variables? Do you think that the results will be unbiased? If not, are there some solutions for dealing with such problems? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this truly a censoring problem? Or is it a zero inflation problem? (Zero-inflated models are a mixture model where one of the distributions is a constant r.v. at 0.)

Comment: Can I apply zero-inflated models with inverse probability weighting estimators?

Comment: You'll have to ask someone who is familiar with inverse probability weighting estimators. I was just pointing out that this doesn't appear to be a censoring problem to me because the values you describe truly are zeros, not an artifact of measurement error.